# Find constants such that the Nyquist criterion is satisfied

Tags: discrete-signals, sampling, homework, nyquist

I have been given the following spectrum, and I want to find a and b such the pulse satisfies the Nyquist criterion, given that the bandwidth of the pulse is 2 kHz and the sampling frequency is 3 kHz. How do i proceed? [image: The given pulse]

Comment: Hi, welcome to DSP.SE! Note that we cannot give you full answers to HW questions especially if you do not show what you have attempted so far. Also HW questions should be tagged as such!

Comment: 1) "the pulse" -- but you show the frequency spectrum?  
2) Interpreting your diagram and words.  Do you mean that input waveforms (pulse?) having frequency content of up to 2khz can be reproduced?  If so, then a 3Khz sampling rate is too low; it must be higher than 4Khz; to be reconstructable unless you know the "pulse" shape.   Unless you have an extrapolatable shape, only signals of 1.5khz can be reconstructed with 3khz sampling.    
3) Your diagram is right in that normal analog filtering will have overlaps of signal and aliasing around the sampling frequency.    You need more detail.